# jstree plugin not working in mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jstree

In an MVC4 application, where should I place the `jstree` folder and `jquery.jstree.js` script file so that it works properly?

If I place jstree folder in the Scripts or Content folder, then a loading image is getting displayed only, without any tree nodes.

My code is:

```
$(function () {
        var $treeview = $('#demo1');
        $treeview.jstree({                       
            'themes':
            {
                theme: "default",
                dots: true,
                icons: true,
                url: "/Content/jsTree/themes/default/style.css"
            },
            'plugins': ['themes', 'ui', 'crrm', 'dnd']       
        })
            .on('loaded.jstree', function () {
             $treeview.jstree('open_all');
         });
    });
```

Comment: Where do you add the file links ? you might need to add the file in master page/ _layout page or page where you add your code.

Comment: Yes I have added file link in the same page where the above code is present.

Comment: you may check in firebug console tab and see if there is any log

Comment: I have checked, no error in firebug console